# Parent DIV height:0px but child element still shows

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

While looking for a way to implement navbar drop down menu (similar to accordion) I came upon [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47DP2db-4k8) which uses custom component and manipulating `max-height` of **card-content** element to achieve the desired effect.

HTML:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-title text-center color="primary" (click)="toggle()"></ion-card-title>
  <ion-card-content #cc>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

CSS:

```
.card-content{
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

TS:

```
toggled = false;
@ViewChild("cc") cc: any;

toggle() {
  if (this.toggled) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.cc.nativeElement, "max-height", "0px");
  } else {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.cc.nativeElement, "max-height", "500px");
  }
  this.toggled = !this.toggled;
}
```

All was working fine while following the video from start to finish.
However what I wanted was a drop down menu from navbar so I decided to edit part of his code to...

```css
#cc{
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ion-navbar text-center color="primary" (click)="toggle()"></ion-navbar>

<div #cc id="cc">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

But it is not working as expected. When div is (0px) i can still see the elements that it contains, in this case it's "Hello World!"

Am I doing something wrong here, or does it only work specifically with ion-cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `overflow: hidden;`

```css
#cc{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ion-navbar text-center color="primary" (click)="toggle()"></ion-navbar>

<div #cc id="cc">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent:

```css
#cc{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ion-navbar text-center color="primary" (click)="toggle()"></ion-navbar>

<div #cc id="cc">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```